# How to create such an iOS interface?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, ios

Would you please have a look at Tipulator app:
http://www.sophiestication.com/tipulator/

I'm interested in the upper graphic part of the application, how to create such an interface?
It doesn't look to use standard UIKit components, it looks like pure graphics yet the values can be updated as a UIKit component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That interface is composed from:

- a background image
- a standard tableView with custom cells

That's it!

Comment: Honestly I don't think they bothered using a table, just custom graphics that make it appear like a table.

Comment: That might be also true. I'm amazed that people don't realise the full extend to which the tableviews can be extended. Maybe because the web counterpart is so inflexible.

Comment: It could also be standard interface elements with custom images in place of them (for the calc.)